# how to read the app.config file of another project

Tags: c#, .net

Suppose I have a project A and project B. I want to access config file of project A in project B then how I can achieve this?

Note: I'm trying to access custom section of the config file as below

```
 var connectionManagerDataSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(ConnectionManagerDataSection.SectionName) as ConnectionManagerDataSection;
        List<AddEndpoint> AddEndpoint = new List<AddEndpoint>();
        if (connectionManagerDataSection != null)
        {
            foreach (MyConfigInstanceElement endpointElement in connectionManagerDataSection.ConnectionManagerEndpoints)
            {
                var endpoint = new AddEndpoint() { Name = endpointElement.Name, Code = endpointElement.Code };
                AddEndpoint.Add(endpoint);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Afaik, all config sections should be placed in `app.config` of startup project

Comment: The `ConfigurationManager` reads the config file of the running executable. So if project B is referenced from project A and you run project A, this works out of the box.

Comment: But I have a config file in both projects A and B . Then how will the project B identifies that it has to access project A's config file

Comment: @krity: As mentioned, it's only the config file of the running executable that is considered. The config file for a class library is not used. You may of course read it like you would read any other XML file if you want to.